# Networking start failed on OVH Proxmox 6.4 if a bridge has no interface

Tags: debian, bridge, proxmox, ovh

We are setting up a new Proxmox 6.4 (based on Debian 10.9) host on OVH (Advance-2) hardware, using the OVH provided template.

In order to create a "virtual" bridge for VMs and LXCs, we added these lines into `/etc/network/interfaces` :

```
auto vmbr1
iface vmbr1 inet static
        address 10.0.1.254/24
        bridge-ports none
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0
```

This configuration works fine on all our Proxmox hosts, but fails on the new machine: reboot takes 20 minutes on "Starting Raise network interfaces", fails with "Failed to start Raise network interfaces" and the bridge interface is not up.

After rebooting without the vmbr1 stuff, I could see that `systemctl restart networking` hangs on "Starting to wait for vmbr1 link to be up"

```
May 12 10:01:49 pve7 ifup[7300]: Waiting for vmbr1 to get ready (MAXWAIT is 2 seconds).
May 12 10:01:49 pve7 ifup[7300]: Disabling IPv6 autoconfiguration for vmbr1
May 12 10:01:49 pve7 ifup[7300]: net.ipv6.conf.vmbr1.accept_ra = 0
May 12 10:01:49 pve7 ifup[7300]: net.ipv6.conf.vmbr1.accept_dad = 0
May 12 10:01:49 pve7 ifup[7300]: net.ipv6.conf.vmbr1.autoconf = 0
May 12 10:01:49 pve7 ifup[7300]: Starting to wait for vmbr1 link to be up at Wed May 12 10:01:49 UTC 2021
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem comes from `/etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wait_for_link_up`, which will wait forever on vmbr1. It looks like this script was recently added by OVH on their Proxmox template, as it does not exist on our older hosts...

Anyway, for now, I fixed the problem by excluding the vmbr1 interface with:

```
if [ "x${IFACE}" = "xvmbr1" ]; then
        exit
fi
```

Comment: this is worst  , this files come with the OVH regular debian buster template . so this is not specific to Proxmox

Comment: The problem has been submitted to OVH Support, who took the problem into account. I hope to see this fixed in the next OVH Proxmox VE 6 distribution.

Comment: The problem has been fixed in OVH Proxmox 6 distribution. The /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wait_for_link_up has been rewritten to wait only for physical devices.